# Pido consejo sobre seguridad

Tags: php, mysql, sql, nodejs, seguridad

pero este quiere pagos con PayPal y stripe y tengo la duda de si debería hacer que las credenciales estén directamente en el código o que se encuentren en una base de datos.

Comment: Si alguien obtiene los dll y descompila tu código estarás en serios problemas. Si buscas *where to store secrets* en google, obtendrás muchos consejos acerca de cómo guardar datos como las credenciales de las que hablas.

Comment: Base de datos. Cuando se trata de datos financieros sensibles como tarjetas de crédito o cuentas bancarias, incluso se debe pensar en múltiples bases de datos, una donde haya una seguridad más alta donde esté esa información más sensible. No solo está en juego la información, si no dinero por demandas si algo fallase.

Comment: Nunca información sensible en el código.